# What are the naming conventions for adding rule references to a new rule set?

Tags: pmd

"Say you want to pick specific rules from various rule sets and customize them. You can do this by making your own rule set."

This sentence can be found here: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.3.3/customizing/howtomakearuleset.html

The PMD Rulesets index for java lists a lot of rulesets. But where can i find the ref-tag which should be used in my own rule set?

For example: If I want to include the "basic" rule set I use the following ref-tag: `<rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml"/>`

But what I have to choose if I would like to include "Clone Implementation"? Is it:

- `<rule ref="rulesets/java/cloneimplementation.xml"/>` or
- `<rule ref="rulesets/java/clone_implementation.xml"/>` or
- `<rule ref="rulesets/java/CloneImplementation.xml"/>` or
- ...

Some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Solution: Download latest version from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd/5.3.3/ and have a look at pmd-java-5.3.3.jar. You will find the *.xml files in rulesets-folder

Answer (score 0):

The rulesets are distributed with PMD in file [`all-java.xml`](https://github.com/adangel/pmd/blob/master/pmd-core/src/main/resources/rulesets/internal/all-java.xml).

Here's its contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<ruleset name="All Java Rules" 
    xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0
            http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>Every Java Rule in PMD</description>

    <rule ref="rulesets/java/android.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/braces.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/clone.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/codesize.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/comments.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/controversial.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/coupling.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/empty.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/imports.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/j2ee.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/javabeans.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/junit.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-jakarta-commons.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-java.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/optimizations.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/sunsecure.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/typeresolution.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml"/>
</ruleset>
```